# How can you share an API key with team members without uploading the key to Github?

Tags: python, github, environment-variables, api-key

I'm working on a project in a small team that is calling an API. What can I do to share the corresponding API key with my teammates but not expose it to Github? Is it possible to set up in a way such that new team members can clone the repo and immediately call the API using the API key?

I initially tried setting up a config.py file that included my API key and added config.py to my gitignore file so that my API key would not be exposed to Github. While this obviously hides the API key from Github, the issue is that now my team members cannot access the API key because the config.py file that includes the key cannot be pulled from Github.

Comment: Use a private repository to upload the api key(s) to.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a private GitHub repository to upload the API key(s) to. If you give your team members the link + access, they can see/use the API key(s). Hope this helps!